# How many table columns are too much in users table?

Tags: database, database-design

for the first time I have to design database at my own.
I went through many tutorials but I want to ask community also.

For example, this is my USER table:

```
Table users {
  id int [pk, increment] // auto-increment
  user_first_name varchar
  user_last_name varchar
  user_email varchar
  user_pass varchar
  user_role varchar
  user_identity_number int (can be NULL, depending on role)
  user_identity_card_front varchar (img URL,can be NULL, depending on role)
  user_identity_card_back varchar (img URL,can be NULL, depending on role)
  user_registered timestamp
}
```

My question is, should I separate this table into more tables, for example users and usersmeta?

Comment: As a user can have more than one Role I would suggest moving that out into another table

Comment: adding to @RiggsFolly 's comment ... based what i am seeing here a normalized model can be..  **user** *(id, first_name, last_name, email, password, registered)*, **role** *(id, front, back)* **user_role** *(number , user_id, role_id)*.  .. (assuming here the user can have multiple roles)

Comment: ... also it is it not clear you also might need to separate identity cards to a separated table if your country allows multiple identifications methods like passport, ID card or driving licence as valid assuming that is what identity number/card/front/back means in this context..

Comment: Thanks, my app will only accept identity card, not passports etc..
Also, user role can be for example admin OR simple_user, you can't be both...I don't know is it helpful information for insight.

Comment: Also, user roles (2) are predefined, users will not be able to add some new role, as I mention in my previous comment.

Comment: Given your requirements, that a person can only hold one role, and there is only a single ID card, then that will be fine. I would change the front/back column names to xxxURL if they always contain a URL. And speaking personally I would get rid of all those underscores and just camel case the names, though that is personal preference.

Comment: Thanks TomC, I thnik you understand requirements. Yes, one user - one role, also, one user-one IDcard..I just wondered why Wordpress split it into two tables, users (id,email,pass,date of reg..) and usermeta (id, userID, meta_key, meta value..) where meta keys are roles, names, adresses... I think that is not necessary?